# Not able to fire oncellselect when tab key is pressed in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to fire the event of oncellselect when tab key is pressed. It works fine as long as cell is selected using a mouse-click. But I notice when tab is pressed, only the event of aftercelledit is fired! Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should describe the scenario which you use more clear. jqGrid have some support of selection of rows by keyboard (see `bindKeys`) but it has no support to select cells.

Probably you use cell editing which use internal `GridNav` method to activate key navigation. In case of cell editing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key activate editing of the next editable cell. So you should use [callbacks of cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) like `beforeEditCell`, `afterEditCell`, `onSelectCell` instead of `onCellSelect` used as the handle of `click` event.

Comment: Yes, I am using onSelectCell for cell editing purpose. But the problem is when I press tab key, it does not call onselectcell...though the cell is selected..

Comment: @faizanjehangir: `onSelectCell` will be called only on not editable cells (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#events)). If the cell in editable the cell will be placed in cell editing mode and `beforeEditCell`, `afterEditCell` etc will be called.